# Center an OpenGL window with GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have an openGL window that is 640x480 that I need to center in the middle of the screen. I previously used:

```
glutInitWindowPosition((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)-640)/2,
                       (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-480)/2);
```

which WORKED.

But now all of a sudden when I compile...

```
Linking...
1>Project1.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000372) "extern "C" int __stdcall GetSystemMetrics(int)" (?GetSystemMetrics@@$$J14YGHH@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(int,char * *)" (?main@@$$HYAHHPAPAD@Z)
1>Project1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall GetSystemMetrics(int)" (?GetSystemMetrics@@$$J14YGHH@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl main(int,char * *)" (?main@@$$HYAHHPAPAD@Z)
1>C:\Users\My Computer\Documents\School Stuff\CS445\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Someone please help. This is very annoying and frustrating for me as I don't know a lot about OpenGL and GLUT.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Also, instead of linking user32.lib you can do it solely using glut:

```
glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) // returns Screen width
```

and

```
glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) // returns Screen height
```

Why depend on Windows when you can be cross-platform?

Hence, your code would look:

```
glutInitWindowPosition((glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH)-640)/2,
                       (glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT)-480)/2);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried using this before and had somehow failed miserably but it is working again with this code thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're linking against User32.lib, the static library where [`GetSystemMetrics()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28VS.85%29.aspx) is defined.  Open up your project settings and make sure the User32.lib is listed among all of the .libs that you're linking against.

Comment: Where is project settings in Visual C++? I didn't mess with anything except the actual code so if this worked before how come it would all of a sudden stop working?

Comment: If you know an alternate way of centering a OpenGL window I would appreciate that as well. Whichever works will be fine, just that this did work and the compiler error is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Okay I found how to get to project properties and linker but where is User32.lib located?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**:
glutInitWindowSize(720, 720);

**Secondly**:
glutInitWindowPosition(600, 200);

**Finally**:
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Window");